# <a> tag is not at the same size of <img> tag inside it

Tags: html, css

I have the following basic HTML content:

```
<div>
    <a href="...">
        <img src="..." width="81" height="75" ... />
    </a>
</div>
```

De-facto, the height of the "A" tag is only 19px, while the image element is set to 75px.

Even when I set the height of the "A" tag manually to 75px, it doesn't get set and stays as is.

The "DIV" element surrounding the "A" tag gets the exact dimensions of the "IMG" element, without setting it manually or anywhere.

The browser is Chrome, latest version.

How do I set the height of the "A" tag correctly, so it always covers (automatically) the entire "IMG" element??

Comment: Why do you need to set a height to the tag? Regardless of its display dimensions it covers the `img` element and any other included element.

Comment: Also try setting `font-size: 0;` for `a`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding `display:inline-block` to the `<a>` element.

Comment: and, very often, `vertical-align: top`

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding a `z-index` to the anchor tag.

```
position: absolute; 
z-index: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `inline-block` declaration is not enough, check the `line-height`…

```
<a href="" style="line-height: 1;">
   <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, `diplay: contents` worked since the element having this property doesn't generate a box with margins/paddings.

From [display: contents doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this (add `id`s):

```
<div>
    <a href="..." id="link">
        <img id="img" src="..." width="81" height="75" ... />
    </a>
</div>
```

And try this javascript

```
document.getElementById("link").style.height=document.getElementById("img").height+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

check this demo on below link

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/4YDz2/)

It is working fine here

Actual image size is 734*459 still it working.

```
<div  >
<a href="#" >
    <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02369/potd-dummy-gull_2369858k.jpg" width="81" height="75"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every combination of answer here but I had to combine line-height in "a" block and vertical-align in the image block.

```
<a href="#" style="line-height: 1;">
    <img id="myimage" src="path" style="vertical-align: bottom;"/>
</a>
```